# Is this Pipe command?

Tags: bash, azure-devops

I see in Azure0-Pipelines.yml file there is an syntax introduction to bash like below:

```
steps:
- bash: |
    which bash
    echo Hello $name
  displayName: Multiline Bash script
  env:
    name: Microsoft
```

I wonder what is the usage of pipe sign after "- bash:", I am pretty new to Bash script, is this still "pipe" bash command ?

Comment: That's not bash syntax, that's yaml syntax that indicates what follows (the bash code) is a [literal block scalar](https://www.yaml.info/learn/quote.html#literal).

Comment: Did you look at the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with l0b0. `|` is one of the many ways to [write a multi-line string in YAML](https://yaml-multiline.info/).

In addition, your mentioned syntax introduction to bash come from this example yaml code: [Bash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#bash).
[image]

Also you could use below classic syntax.

```
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      which bash
      echo Hello $name
  displayName: Multiline Bash script
  env:
    name: Microsoft
```

See: [Bash task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?view=azure-devops) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

`|` is one of the many ways to [write a multi-line string in YAML](https://yaml-multiline.info/).